# Test a header was added using Mockk

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockk

I am trying to write a test that checks if a header was added to a request when I call the intercept method on my custom interceptor class. I am getting a **no answer found exception** when I run the **sendsNewContractHeaderToRequest** test and am not sure how to modify my test so that it passes. I think it's because I am not mockking the proceed call but I'm not sure how to do that in this situation.

no answer found for: Chain(#1).proceed(Request{method=GET, url=http://somehost/somepath, headers=[foo:bar, Contract:new]})
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for: Chain(#1).proceed(Request{method=GET, url=http://somehost/somepath, headers=[foo:bar, Contract:new]})

Here are my 2 classes:

```
class ContractInterceptor(private val contractType: ContractType) : Interceptor {

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response = try {
    chain.proceed(
        chain.request()
            .newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Contract", contractType.headerValue)
            .build()
    )
} catch (ex: IOException) {
    Response.Builder()
        .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_2)
        .request(chain.request())
        .code(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR)
        .message(ex.localizedMessage)
        .body("Internal Server Error".toResponseBody("application/json".toMediaType()))
        .build()
}

enum class ContractType(val headerValue: String) {
    NEW("new"), V2("v2"), V3("v3")
}}
```

And this is my test class

```
class ContractInterceptorTest {

private val mockChain: Interceptor.Chain = mockk {
    every { request() } returns Request.Builder()
        .url("http://somehost/somepath")
        .addHeader("foo", "bar")
        .build()
}

@Test
fun sendsNewContractHeaderToRequest() {
    ContractInterceptor(ContractInterceptor.ContractType.NEW)
        .intercept(mockChain)

    val slot = slot<Request>()
    verify { mockChain.proceed(capture(slot)) }

    assertThat(slot.captured.headers.size == 2)
    assertThat(slot.captured.headers["Contract"] == "new")
    assertThat(slot.captured.headers["foo"] == "bar")
}

@Test
fun returns500WhenIOExceptionThrown() {
    every { mockChain.proceed(any()) } throws IOException("An Exception!")

    val response = ContractInterceptor(ContractInterceptor.ContractType.NEW)
        .intercept(mockChain)

    assertThat(response).isNotNull
    assertThat(response.code).isEqualTo(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it's necessary to make the mockking of the proceed method.

```kotlin
private val mockChain: Interceptor.Chain = mockk(relaxed = true) {
        every { request() } returns Request.Builder()
            .url("http://somehost/somepath")
            .addHeader("foo", "bar")
            .build()
        
        every { proceed(any()) } returns Response.Builder()
            .request(request)
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
            .code(200)
            .message("Test")
            .body("abc".toResponseBody())
            .build()
    }
```